# Vue 3: Composition API with external templates

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

So, I come from Angular world where by default we are separating view from business logic... and I don't like  single file components, especially when they are getting bigger and convoluted.

Before in vue 2, I would have myComponent.vue with script tag and have it like so:

```
<template src="./myComponent.html"></template>
```

To call the view file... and it would work... all the methods were accessible

but now, if I use the setup way

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  const suggets = () => {
  }
</script>

<template src="./myComponent.html"></template>
```

I would get a typescript error that suggest was declared and never used...

Also for example:
`<carbon-search />` component would not work

> Failed to resolve component: carbon-search If this is a native custom
> element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via
> compilerOptions.isCustomElement.

Any good and elegant way to split the component view and business logic (and css)?

Comment: You are already using vue-3, instead of focusing on the template to separate the concerns, use hooks with the composition api and use those hooks in the template.

Comment: honestly, have no idea of what are you talking about.,... maybe an example?